# Vector rotation problem

Tags: c++, linear-algebra, inverse-kinematics

I'm working on a program with IK and have run into what I had at first thought was a trivial problem but have since had trouble solving it.

Background:

Everything is in 3d space.
I'm using 3d Vectors and Quaternions to represent transforms.

I have a limb which we will call V1. 
I want to rotate it onto V2.

I was getting the angle between V1 and V2.
Then the axis for rotation by V1 cross V2.

Then making a Quaternion from the axis and angle.

I then take the limbs current Orientation and multiply it by the axis angle quaternion.

This I believe is my desired local space for the limb.

This limb is attached to a series of other links. To get the world space I traverse up to the root combining the parents local space with the child's local space until I reach the root.

This seems to work grand if the vector that I am rotating to is contained within the X and Y plane or if the body which the limb is attached to hasn't been modified. If anything has been modified, for example rotating the root node, then on the first iteration the vector will rotate very close to the desired vector. After that point though it will begin to spin all over the place and never reach the goal.

I've gone through all the math line by line and it appears to all be correct. I'm not sure if there is something that I do not know about or am simply over looking. Is my logical sound? Or am I unaware of something? Any help is greatly appreciated!

```
Quaternion::Quaternion(const Vector& axis, const float angle)
{
float sin_half_angle = sinf( angle / 2 );

v.set_x( axis.get_x() * sin_half_angle );
v.set_y( axis.get_y() * sin_half_angle );
v.set_z( axis.get_z() * sin_half_angle );

w = cosf( angle / 2 );
}

Quaternion Quaternion::operator* (const Quaternion& quat) const
{

Quaternion result;

Vector v1( this->v );
Vector v2( quat.v  );

float s1 = this->w;
float s2 = quat.w;

result.w  = s1 * s2 - v1.Dot(v2);
result.v  = v2 * s1 + v1 * s2 + v1.Cross(v2); 

result.Normalize();

return result;
}

Vector Quaternion::operator* (const Vector& vec) const
{

Quaternion quat_vec(vec.get_x(), vec.get_y(), vec.get_z(), 0.0f);
Quaternion rotation( *this );

Quaternion rotated_vec = rotation * ( quat_vec * rotation.Conjugate() ); 

return rotated_vec.v;
}

Quaternion Quaternion::Conjugate()
{
    Quaternion result( *this );
    result.v = result.v * -1.0f;
    return result; 
}

Transform Transform::operator*(const Transform tran)
{
return Transform( mOrient * transform.getOrient(), mTrans + ( mOrient *   tran.getTrans());
}

Transform Joint::GetWorldSpace()
{       
Transform world = local_space;

Joint* par = GetParent();

while ( par ) 
{
    world = par->GetLocalSpace() * world;
    par = par->GetParent();
}

return world;
}

void RotLimb()
{
Vector end_effector_worldspace_pos = end_effector->GetWorldSpace().get_Translation();
Vector parent_worldspace_pos       = parent->GetWorldSpace().get_Translation();

Vector parent_To_end_effector      = ( end_effector_worldspace_pos - parent_worldspace_pos ).Normalize(); 
Vector parent_To_goal              = ( goal_pos                    - parent_worldspace_pos ).Normalize(); 

float dot = parent_To_end_effector.Dot( parent_To_goal );

Vector rot_axis(0.0f,0.0f,1.0f);
float  angle = 0.0f;

if (1.0f - fabs(dot) > EPSILON) 
{
    //angle    = parent_To_end_effector.Angle( parent_To_goal );            
    rot_axis = parent_To_end_effector.Cross( parent_To_goal ).Normalize();

    parent->RotateJoint( rot_axis, acos(dot) );
}
}

void Joint::Rotate( const Vector& axis, const float rotation )
{
    mLocalSpace = mlocalSpace * Quaternion( axis, rotation );
}
```

Comment: Did you make sure it's not a numerical precision issue? I don't know which iterative algorithm you're using, but it may not converge in the presence of numerical errors. Perhaps you need to make the minimum acceptable error higher, or consider using another numerical data type

Comment: I agree with sinelaw. At some point your algorithm has to say "Close enough" and just assign the value to be equal to the target value.

Comment: Could you provide formulas or (pseudo-)code? It's difficult to guess what went wrong without more details. The only thing I can give you is that the rotations in 2d space is commutative, maybe you mixed up the order of multiplication somewhere?

Comment: Most people here are severely lacking in the clairvoyance department. You have to show your code. I suspect you don't update limb's local space correctly after a rotation, but I'm shooting in the dark here.

Comment: @sinelaw - I had thought that it might be that as well. It seems that it doesn't converge after the first rotation though. I'd have to set the tolerance too high. It make me believe that something else must be wrong.

Comment: @Nocturn - Sorry I should have been more clear. I've edited the question to include what I believe is the relevant source code. After looking farther into things it appears that if I rotate the vector using the created rotation, it rotates correct. for example modified_parent_to_effedctor = rot * parent_to_end_effector; modified_parent then points in the right direction and has been rotated correctly. When I add this rotation into the joints local space it isn't correct. It seems that I have some concatenation issue when combining quaternions. Any ideas?

Comment: @user964426: I don't think I can help you in the way you think I can :(. There's active and passive transformations. It matters a lot and quaternions is indirectly linked to rotation. What you need are upgrades to your 3d engine. Add visualization code to display: the axis of the local world. Add code to see the axis of rotation. Not relevant to your problem but also boundary boxes/spheres. Mathematics can be tackled by visualizing it or formulating it. I'm confident once you see it, you'll really see it and solve it.

Comment: @Nocturn: Ah no worries. I actually have a lot of debug code which shows the rotation axis. It seems that the rotation axis will start going crazy as time goes on. After re looking at this code I'm wondering if this issue is occuring because I'm doing the calculations to get the axis and angle in the world space for the joint, but then applying it to the local space. This is easy enough to check, so I'll try that. Thanks for the insight though!

Comment: @user964426: :) stackoverflow is only the programming side of things.  Check out the math section of this network and post your question there. I've studied pure mathematics and it is unreal the insights I've learned from their answers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are correct when you write in a comment that the axis should be computed in the local coordinate frame of the joint:

> I'm wondering if this issue is occuring because I'm doing the calculations to get the axis and angle in the world space for the joint, but then applying it to the local space.

The rotation of the axis from the world frame to the joint frame will look something like this:

```
rot_axis = parent->GetWorldSpace().Inverse().get_Rotation() * rot_axis
```

There can be other issues to debug, but it's the only logical error I can see in the code that you have posted.

Comment: After writing that comment, I went home and tested the issue. Sure enough that was the problem and i simply added the code to convert the axis to the local space of the joint... Everything worked perfectly then. Funny the things we overlook sometimes... i forgot about this post til just now and saw this answer. it is spot on to what i did. I appreciate you taking the time to respond.